# How to split a document in OpenXML SDK

Tags: c#, .net, split, openxml, openxml-sdk

I need to split a document in OpenXml sdk 2.0.  The document has sections that each have a footer with a text element (name of the section).  Is there a straightforward way to copy from one OpenXml document to another?

Answer (score 3):

DocumentBuilder is the tool you are looking for.  See for example, http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericwhite/archive/2010/01/08/how-to-control-sections-when-using-openxml-powertools-documentbuilder.aspx

Comment: I was able to make this work but I had to remove all of the images from my document first.  It only works with embedded images or it errors out...

Answer (score 3):

This would require a lot of work on your part to copy and merge stylesheets among other things.  I'd recommend using [altChunk](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.wordprocessing.altchunk.aspx) to do the merging for you as it will take care of all the hard stuff for you.  Here are two links to help explain it more: [How to Use altChunk for Document Assembly](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericwhite/archive/2008/10/27/how-to-use-altchunk-for-document-assembly.aspx) and [How to: Assemble Multiple Word Processing Documents in One](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd611007.aspx)

Comment: @jle - I might be not understanding exactly what you mean by "split off". Altchunk will take sections from various word docs and split them out so you can merge them into a new document of your choosing. Do you not have access to creating a templated word doc so you can use this?  Otherwise you are going to have a really hard time getting all the styles to look right by doing the splitting manually.

Comment: I want to divide a document into sections based on the sections in the document.

Answer (score 0):

I have done similar to what you describe using just the OpenXmlSDK. Though I have to say it wasn't much fun, and I was left wanting a solution I didn't have to carve myself. In my case I had to keep footers/headers etc. with section content and split the document into several other documents.

At the time I couldn't locate any samples on identifying which section an element belonged to, and had to write a utility myself. (The way word splits sections is by injecting a section break *after* the content, and the SDK didn't seem to provide any helpers.) I then had to locate the header definition by using the headerReference and grab that content too, before creating a new document and injecting the header, footer, and section content.

I wish you the best of luck!